# R: Using group and summarize to make a pivot table

Tags: r, pivot, pivot-table, tidyverse

Edit: New approach with pivot table help

Everyone,

Now I messed up somehow while editing other stuff. What I have is a data Frame

```
    PARK     WEA     CODE  
 1 BEEBE 01WEA82345 FM1142
 2 BEEBE 01WEA82345 FM1142
 3 BEEBE 01WEA82345 FM1142
 4 BEEBE 05WEA82341 FM400 
 5 BEEBE 05WEA82341 FM700 
 6 BEEBE 05WEA82341 FM700 
 7 BEEBE 13WEA82316 FM545 
 8 BEEBE 13WEA82316 FM545 
 9 BEEBE 14WEA82321 FM359 
10 BEEBE 16WEA82319 FM400
```

Code I originally had and is not working

```
     Sick_WTG_USA <- SWTGQuery %>% group_by(PARK, WEA, CODE) %>% 
        arrange(PARK, WEA, CODE) %>% 
        summarise(FMcount = n())
```

Now what I am looking to do is (pivot):

```
   PARK     WEA        CODE    FMcount
 1 BEEBE 01WEA82345 FM1142     3
 2 BEEBE 05WEA82341 FM400      1
 3 BEEBE 05WEA82341 FM700      2 
 4 BEEBE 13WEA82316 FM545      2
 5 BEEBE 14WEA82321 FM359      1
 6 BEEBE 16WEA82319 FM400      1
```

Just like if I ran a pivot table in excel.

what would be the best for simple pivot tables.

Comment: You probably have some package with its own summarise function and are using that instead of dplyr's, so are seeing the usual (unclear) error message from `dplyr::n()`

Comment: If you want/need further help, it would be useful to have usable data, not an image of it. Several reasons are immediate: I cannot copy code or data from your image into my R console and try it out, and I choose to not transcribe it manually. Some reasons are slightly less obvious but still important, including: it breaks screen readers *hard*; search engines don't read them, so searches will not find it; mobile device screen size might be a limiting factor. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272. (Suggestion: `dput(x)` or `dput(head(x))`.)

Comment: r2evans thanks for the advice

Comment: Thanks Frank I will see what I am missing

Comment: Stupid question; how do I add a data frame to the above question and not a pic.

Comment: Paste your data frame data into the box, select them, Ctrl-K to format as code or add 4 spaces before each row. Leave a blank line before and after the data.

Comment: I found my answer. Thank you all. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36299541/10241715

Answer (score 0):

Why is this not working? I recreated your data, ran your code and got the output you were hoping to get:

```
library(tidyverse)

SWTGQuery <- tibble(
  PARK = "BEEBE",
  WEA = c(
  "01WEA82345", "01WEA82345", "01WEA82345",
  "05WEA82341", "05WEA82341", "05WEA82341",
  "13WEA82316", "13WEA82316", "14WEA82321", "16WEA82319"
  ),
  CODE = c(
  "FM1142", "FM1142", "FM1142", "FM400", "FM700",
  "FM700", "FM545", "FM545", "FM359", "FM400"
  )
)

Sick_WTG_USA <- SWTGQuery %>% 
  group_by(PARK, WEA, CODE) %>% 
  arrange(PARK, WEA, CODE) %>% 
  summarise(FMcount = n())

Sick_WTG_USA
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   PARK, WEA [?]
#>   PARK  WEA        CODE   FMcount
#>   <chr> <chr>      <chr>    <int>
#> 1 BEEBE 01WEA82345 FM1142       3
#> 2 BEEBE 05WEA82341 FM400        1
#> 3 BEEBE 05WEA82341 FM700        2
#> 4 BEEBE 13WEA82316 FM545        2
#> 5 BEEBE 14WEA82321 FM359        1
#> 6 BEEBE 16WEA82319 FM400        1
```

Comment: I got it to work, for some reason i missed the library load of library(dpylr). ONce I closed out my Rstudio session after work and restarted at home, and reloaded it all it worked. I think in my edits during my session I messed up some where and unloaded (dpylr).

Comment: Also thanks for the help